# AES key decryption not working

Tags: java, cryptography

I need to encrypt an AES Key with RSA's public key, I read a couple of articles and some questions from stack overflow too, I managed to do the algorithm but I'm not a java programmer although I need to do this in java, so I think my problem here could be more a syntax problem. 
My code is encrypting the AES key (don't know if it's encrypting how it should) but when I decrypt it, it's not the same, my output:

Original  AES key:          [B@48e5707f

Encrypted AES Key with RSA: [B@adea215

Decrypted AES Key:          [B@7b4b5d3f

Also, everytime I compile and run, the AES key is always the same, same with RSA, shouldn't be different?

My code:

```
public class Rsa {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    //RSA init
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(512);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

    //AES init
    KeyGenerator keyGen2 = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGen2.init(192);
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGen2.generateKey();
    byte[] encoded = secretKey.getEncoded(); 
    System.out.println("Original  AES key:"+ encoded);

    //Encrypting AES with RSA
    Cipher cipher  = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] encryptedMsg = cipher.doFinal(encoded);
    System.out.println("Encrypted AES Key with RSA:" + encryptedMsg);

    //Decrypting AES with RSA
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] decryptedMsg = cipher.doFinal(encryptedMsg);
    System.out.println("Decrypted AES Key:" + decryptedMsg);

}
```

Comment: I read about padding and how it can generate some problems, but I couldn't use them since I was getting some errors, but I don't know if my problem is because I'm using raw RSA/AES

Comment: Not related to your problem, but 512 bit is an awfully short RSA-key. The strength of the wrapper should always be stronger than the key you are wrapping, so an AES 192bit key should be wrapped in at least a 1024bit RSA. In fact better use 2048 bit RSA to be prepared for larger AES keys.

Comment: I need to do this with 512 bit, it's in my specification,but I will see if I can use 2048.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you're seeing is not the content of the byte array, but its memory address (or a representation thereof). You probably want to hex encode the byte array to a string and then output that string to be able to compare the contents.

Your output is different because it's two different byte array objects, but that doesn't mean that their contents are not the same.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I'm trying to do what you said but I didn't understand the "You probably want to hex encode the byte array to a string".

Comment: This blog post describes an easy way to do it: http://www.dev-garden.org/2013/04/16/java-byte-array-as-a-hex-string-the-easy-way/